# Select not getting submitted with the form

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="map-form">
    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from1" size="8">
        <option value="Email">Field Email</option>
        <option value="ID">Field ID</option>
        <option value="name">Field name</option>
        <option value="address">Field address</option>
        <option value="city">Field city</option>
        <option value="state">Field state</option>
        <option value="country">Field country</option>
        <option value="sex">Field sex</option>
    </select>
    <select name="slectfrom1[]" id="select-from2" size="8">
        <option value="id">Field id</option>
        <option value="name">Field name</option>
        <option value="email">Field email</option>
        <option value="address">Field address</option>
        <option value="city">Field city</option>
        <option value="state">Field state</option>
        <option value="designation">Field designation</option>
        <option value="sex">Field sex</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="btn-add">Add »</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-remove">« Remove</button>
    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple=""></select>
    <input type="text" name="vein" value="aaa">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I was facing a strange issue with hmtl form. The select field was not getting submitted.

Then I found a strange solution which is beyond my understanding

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="map-form">
    <select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from1" size="8" form="map-form">
        <option value="Email">Field Email</option>
        <option value="ID">Field ID</option>
        <option value="name">Field name</option>
        <option value="address">Field address</option>
        <option value="city">Field city</option>
        <option value="state">Field state</option>
        <option value="country">Field country</option>
        <option value="sex">Field sex</option>
    </select>
    <select name="slectfrom1[]" id="select-from2" size="8" form="map-form">
        <option value="id">Field id</option>
        <option value="name">Field name</option>
        <option value="email">Field email</option>
        <option value="address">Field address</option>
        <option value="city">Field city</option>
        <option value="state">Field state</option>
        <option value="designation">Field designation</option>
        <option value="sex">Field sex</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" id="btn-add">Add »</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-remove">« Remove</button>
    <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple="" form="map-form"></select>
    <input type="text" name="vein" value="aaa">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see in the solution the select field has form attribute which is the form id.
Can anyone tell me why this need to be done as i am facing this issue for the first time. Also is there any alternate solution or I am missing something.
One more thing to add: the select option are getting generated dynamically in php.

action.php code

```
<?php 
echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [vein] => aaa
)
```

The php file whith whole code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "PHPExcel.php";
include 'database.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$db = Database::getInstance();
$con = $db->getConnection();
$excel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("uploads/upload_test.xls");
//echo"<pre>";print_r($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets());die;
$highestColumm = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$allCellValue = array();
//echo '<table border="1">';
foreach ($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    //echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        if (!is_null($cell)) {
            $allCellValue[] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            //echo '<td>';
            //echo $value . '&nbsp;';
            //echo '</td>';
        }
    }
    //echo '</tr>';
}

$row = 1;
$firstCellValue = array();
for ($column = 'A'; $column != $highestColumm; $column++) {
    $firstCellValue[] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$row)->getValue();
}
$dbColumns = array();
$query = "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'dynamic_forms' and table_name = 'employee'";
if($output = $con->query($query)):
    while($result = $output->fetch_assoc()):
        $dbColumns[] = $result['column_name'];
    endwhile;
endif;
//echo '</table>';
//echo"<pre>";print_r($firstCellValue);
//echo"<pre>";print_r($allCellValue);
//die;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database Field Mapping from Excel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="action.php" method="post" >
            <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from1" size="<?php echo count($firstCellValue); ?>">
            <?php foreach($firstCellValue as $excelField){ ?>    
                <option value="<?php echo $excelField; ?>">Field <?php echo $excelField; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>    
            </select>

            <select name="slectfrom1" id="select-from2" size="<?php echo count($dbColumns); ?>">
            <?php foreach($dbColumns as $dbField){ ?>    
                <option value="<?php echo $dbField; ?>">Field <?php echo $dbField; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</button>

            <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple ></select>
            <input type="text" name="vein" value="aaa"/>
            </br><button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn-add').click(function(){

            var selected1 = $('#select-from1 option:selected');
            var selected2 = $('#select-from2 option:selected');

            if(selected1.length == 0 || selected2.length == 0){
              alert("Please select options from both the select boxes");
              return;
            }

            $('#select-to').append("<option data-val1='"+selected1.val()+"' data-val2='"+selected2.val()+"' data-text1='"+selected1.text()+"' data-text2='"+selected2.text()+"' value='"+selected1.val()+"+"+selected2.val()+"'>"+selected1.text()+"+"+selected2.text()+"</option>");
            selected1.remove();
            selected2.remove();

        });
        $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
            $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                var select1_val = $(this).attr("data-val1");
                var select2_val = $(this).attr("data-val2");
                var select1_text = $(this).attr("data-text1");
                var select2_text = $(this).attr("data-text2");

                $('#select-from1').append("<option value='"+select1_val+"'>"+select1_text+"</option>");
                $('#select-from2').append("<option value='"+select2_val+"'>"+select2_text+"</option>");
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

html page after adding option to third select

```
<html><head>
        <title>Database Field Mapping from Excel</title>
    </head>
    <body style="zoom: 1;">
        <form action="action.php" method="post">
            <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from1" size="8">

                <option value="Email">Field Email</option>

                <option value="ID">Field ID</option>

                <option value="name">Field name</option>





                <option value="state">Field state</option>

                <option value="country">Field country</option>

                <option value="sex">Field sex</option>

            </select>

            <select name="slectfrom1" id="select-from2" size="8">

                <option value="id">Field id</option>

                <option value="name">Field name</option>

                <option value="email">Field email</option>

                <option value="address">Field address</option>

                <option value="city">Field city</option>





                <option value="sex">Field sex</option>
                        </select>
            <button type="button" id="btn-add">Add »</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn-remove">« Remove</button>

            <select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple=""><option data-val1="city" data-val2="state" data-text1="Field city" data-text2="Field state" value="city+state">Field city+Field state</option><option data-val1="address" data-val2="designation" data-text1="Field address" data-text2="Field designation" value="address+designation">Field address+Field designation</option></select>
            <input type="text" name="vein" value="aaa">
            <br><button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn-add').click(function(){

            var selected1 = $('#select-from1 option:selected');
            var selected2 = $('#select-from2 option:selected');

            if(selected1.length == 0 || selected2.length == 0){
              alert("Please select options from both the select boxes");
              return;
            }

            $('#select-to').append("<option data-val1='"+selected1.val()+"' data-val2='"+selected2.val()+"' data-text1='"+selected1.text()+"' data-text2='"+selected2.text()+"' value='"+selected1.val()+"+"+selected2.val()+"'>"+selected1.text()+"+"+selected2.text()+"</option>");
            selected1.remove();
            selected2.remove();

        });
        $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
            $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
                $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                var select1_val = $(this).attr("data-val1");
                var select2_val = $(this).attr("data-val2");
                var select1_text = $(this).attr("data-text1");
                var select2_text = $(this).attr("data-text2");

                $('#select-from1').append("<option value='"+select1_val+"'>"+select1_text+"</option>");
                $('#select-from2').append("<option value='"+select2_val+"'>"+select2_text+"</option>");
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>    

</body></html>
```

Comment: selectfrom[] .. Lokks like invalid characters in name.

Comment: Can you show us your `action.php`code? Or at least the dump from your `$_POST` superglobal after the post

Comment: Try to avoid `<button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>`. If you want a submit button use `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

Comment: `name="slectfrom1[]"` Could that be the real problem

Comment: Fairly sure that the `multiple=""` attribute should be just `multiple`

Comment: Do this form forwarding to action.php??

Comment: @AedixRhinedale updated it in the question

Comment: Rename your `select`s, remove those brackets, they won't serve you any role. Standardize its names and try again.

Comment: `slectfrom1[]` means multiselect but you can't without adding `multiple`

Comment: tried renaming it but still same issue.

Comment: It works fine with me... With which browser ?

Comment: Having a `<select name="selectto[]" id="select-to" multiple="" form="map-form"></select>` without any `<option>` makes me think there is some javascript being used on the form. Could that be damaging something by accident

Comment: @RiggsFolly nemaed it and tried but still same issue and yes you are right  multiple="" is multiple but still not working.

Comment: Based on the comments and your code, there is nothing more to *not work* anymore, something is missing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes there is java script but thats on button click and not on submit. so i guess it has no role to play.

Comment: @SwapnilShende As i said everything works very fine with me. You are hidding something to us that you think "not important"

Comment: Your both two forms are working correctly for me. there is no problem in your code

Comment: @SwapnilShende did you follow Hearner s hint and changed your <button type="submit"> to <input type="submit">?

Comment: _select field has form attribute which is the form id_ this is just a HTML5 mechanism to allow inputs to be outside a `<form></form>` but still be included when the form is submitted. Normally used when you have 2 or more forms on a page.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale yes tried input type submit. but in vain.

Comment: I tried your code and found it is working just by renaming. I tried your first set of code.

Comment: Like I've said, something is missing. Show us your **full updated** HTML code.

Comment: You had better refresh your _solution_ in your question, so we can see exactly what has been changed and what has not!!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly attaching the whole code.

Comment: What I can think of so far: a) `multiple` is empty when it [should be](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple) `yes`. b) there is no need for bracketed names if your select isn't multiple. c) It's worth remembering that some value *should be selected* prior to submitting the form.

Comment: Well that update changes things a little.

Comment: @SwapnilShende If you are using array based name then your both select should have same names: `name="selectfrom[]"`.

Comment: @Jai no it shouldn't, `$_POST` will overwrite the previous one with the next if you do it.

Comment: @Jai why should both select have same name. I dont think this is correct way.

Comment: @SwapnilShende i don't work on php but it seemed like that.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale your c) point is correct. but in my application when i select option from both select and click add it removes the respective options from select and add it in the third select. and then i click submit.

Comment: Who is suggesting using this `select column_name from information_schema.columns` This is the third time this week I have seen someone doing this. **Is that not equivalent to** `select * from` You should really not be using MYSQL's own database. One silly move and you have totally destroyed MYSQL **especially if you are just a beginner**

Comment: @RiggsFolly judging by his resulting html source, it's somehow working.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale Oh it will work, my question is **WHY** Who or what tutorial is suggestiong this?

Comment: @SwapnilShende did you tested Add and Remove functions? Can you show some HTML source **after** you sum up the values from the 2 selects into the third one?

Comment: @RiggsFolly million dollar one

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is not a santized code i will be using mysqli and a different query.  but my aim was to quickly finish up with main functionality.

Comment: i saw it here and twisted it to good effect http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

Comment: [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com) explains a lot

Comment: @AedixRhinedale added HTML source after you sum up the values from the 2 selects into the third one

Answer (score 0):

Why you have array name for select?

array name is only applicable for multiple select, check box.

instead of

> `<select name="selectfrom[]" id="select-from1" size="8">`

Try this

> `<select name="selectfrom" id="select-from1" size="8">`

Comment: _Why you have array name for select?_ It helps in sending multiple values. Haven't you used as you are a php-coder.

Comment: He said it on the answer.

Comment: jai brother just check the answer as i said "Multiple select "

Comment: @php-coder hehehe just missed it, great one. but you can see there are two select elements and OP has different name for them. which should be same. i guess.